# Looking for an "Acid test" visual HTML page

Tags: html, css, demo, lorem-ipsum

I'm looking for an HTML page that has an instance of every possible visual element on it: `li`'s with every bullet type, every text formatting option, background-images with various alignments, css drop-shadows, css gradients, etc, etc...

Anyone know of one?

(since someone will ask) The reason I need this is that I'm writing a screenshot app that is attempting to clone the current page into a canvas so I can save it off as a png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody is answering this, I'm working on creating my own:

http://html2canvas.clientsite.me/tests/kitchen_sink.html

---

About the page: If you click anywhere on the page it will re-render everything into a canvas element, so that I can save it off as a .png

For anyone interested:

- other tests: http://canvasrenderer.clientsite.me/
- github: https://github.com/cwolves/CanvasRenderer

Comment: The canvas part isn't accurate at all... I wouldn't nitpick about it, but you're trying to test the rendering engines and your testing engine is flawed. On Chrome 14 the canvas is completely different from the normal rendering, even the z-index test up top. -- Unless you claim that Chrome's rendering engine isn't up to norm, which while possible, it passes Acid3 with 100%.

Comment: @Blindy - I started this project 2 days ago.  I'm re-rendering the entire page by converting HTML bit-by-bit to a canvas.  The point of this test is to find issues with the engine so I can fix them :)

Comment: Right, just giving feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you instead focus not on the HTML elements, but the various /type/ of elements and trust that the "current page" canvas that you're exporting the image from is able to render it.

You want to instead test things like:

1. Typical HTML elements - `<h1>`, `<p>`, `<b>`, and the like work.
2. Typical pages that are modified using javascript.
3. Pages that use flash in some form.
4. Pages that use so-called 'HTML5' elements, such as video.
5. Other non-typical components, such as SVG, inline frames, advertisements.
6. Elements that shouldn't be copied, such as password fields.

Also, you'll want to ensure that doing the screenshot doesn't reload the page, that could be fatal.

Comment: I'm using the page's rendered interpretation to give me positioning and things like font-weight of everything on the page, so I already have 90%+ of the page rendering correctly.  What I'm down to are the things that I mentioned along with a couple of background-position and z-index bugs.  I'm ignoring flash, since there is no way to take a screenshot of it client-side.

Comment: Client side normally is how flash is used. Any particular reason you aren't happy with existing renderers?

Comment: The point of this is to allow me to take a screenshot of the current page, something not possible client-side without a plugin.  It has nothing to do with me not being happy with existing renderers, it has to do with this being the only possible solution :)

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that you can't take a screenshot from, eg, a gecko or webkit-based control.

Comment: I'm sure people have rendered Qt or GTK controls to an image! Heck, I KNOW that Qt and GTK both render to a wide variety of different backends.

Comment: ___client-side!!!___ I need this to work from a browser without any external dependencies

Comment: You have a very peculiar definition of 'client side'. :)

Comment: web dev client-side = from a browser.  i.e. javascript/html/css

Comment: That's not the normal definition of client side - but now your question does make sense.  I suggest revising your question to make it (much) clearer.

Comment: My question is clear has nothing to do with this, it's this thread that threw you :)  And it is the normal definition of client-side.  client-side = work that the client does in a client-server communication.  Extrapolate that to "website client side has to be OS agnostic" and you get "what a browser can do".